# Set scale to always show at least 1 point on map as well as users location

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ios5

If I had x amount of locations in a mapview, and I wanted to make sure that 1 location point was always visible as well as the users location, what's the best way to go about this? I realise it boils to setting the scale on the map, but I'm just not sure the best way to calculate this. I'm new to objective-c , but I guess I'm mainly after a formula for calculating this rather than any specific code.

For instance if a user is in France, but the nearest location is in the UK, I want to show their position and at least one of the nearest locations in my app. I realise this could be a poor user experience if a user is thousands of miles away but this is the requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate MKMapRect from yours locations and then set it in [setVisibleMapRect:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).